# facebook graph api pages post message

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wanted to make a facebook API request that will post a message to page that I am admin of. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing) i found out how can i do that but after trying it out in facebook graph api explorer with this scheme:

```
 graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed
  ?message=Hello&access_token=your-access-token"
```

assuming I have a developer account linked to my page and publish_pages and manage_pages permissions are enabled and page-id and acces-token are replaced with my real ones. The problem is that I get a response of latest post on that website, the same as if I would write just `graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed` and there is no new post on my page. 
I dont know if the recent facebook API update removed or modified that or if its just not possible.

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted to better understand your issue and find the proper solution. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> trying it out in facebook graph api explorer with this scheme
>
> ```
> graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed?message=Hello&access_token=your-access-token
> ```

You are making a GET request here - and GET is for reading data, not creating it.

Creating data requires a POST request. So you can either switch the request method from `GET` to `POST` via the dropdown there, and then click `+ Add parameter` to add your parameters and values;

or you can add `&method=post` to the end of your GET request query string here - that is a way the API offers to explicitly overwrite the request method in environments, where you can only make GET requests.

Comment: Thanks, i totally forgot about that